# How to start afresh with One Drive with the same live.com account but with a new Laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-11, onedrive

I had OneDrive on my older Laptop where a lot of stuff was backed up. Now I moved to a new Laptop - I didn't want the same directory structure as the old Laptop, so I manually downloaded stuff from https://onedrive.live.com on my new laptop & rearranged the files & deleted stuff which is no longer needed. I then deleted everything from https://onedrive.live.com also. So now when I go to https://onedrive.live.com, the only thing I see is PersonalVault (I haven't deleted it because I am not sure what it is).

Now when I press Control Esc & type OneDrive, it shows a directory Icon labelled OneDrive app & when I run it, it seems to open a directory which contains several of my old directories - it's not clear where these directories are stored (can't even figure out if it's showing something local or on the cloud). It's not everything I had on it earlier but more 70%.

How do I reset OneDrive while using the same live.com id & start afresh on what to backup on my new laptop?

I am running Windows 11 Home Single Language 22H2 OS Build 22621.2715

Comment: Sign out of the OneDrive app on the laptop, re-sign in, and look for the option before fully completing sign-in that allows you to set a custom location other than `%UserProfile%\OneDrive`, which I think is labeled as _Advanced_, _Custom_,, or something along those lines

Comment: You have to start the synchronization to update the folder contents

Comment: @Ramhound - that works - if you write out your comment as an answer, I can accept it.